# The model backing my context has changed

Tags: c#-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have a class library project where my POCO classes live along with a Dbcontext.  I am using Code First with data migrations and everything has gone great up to this point.  I use the class library in a console application test project and it still works fine there, but I am also trying to use the same exact class library in an MVC project and I get a "The model backing the context has changed since the database was created".  Whenever I make a change to the model, I do the database migration update and everything goes well.  The model has not still works in the console application just fine.

I have this method in a controller where I am trying to access the context:

```
 public MultiSelectList GetListOfPossibleDispositions()
    {
    List<DALDevices3.Dispositions> dispositions = new List<Dispositions>();
    dispositions =   context.Dispositions.GroupBy(d=>d.Description).Select(grp=>grp.First()).ToList();
    dispositions.OrderBy(d=>d.Description);
    selectListDispositions = new MultiSelectList(dispositions, "id", "Description");
    context.Dispose();
    return selectListDispositions;
    }
```

Any thought on what might be causing this issue or a possible work around ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you connecting to the same database?

Comment: Yes.  I am connecting to the same database.

Comment: The same model, from the same .dll but from two different projects and one of them raises this exception?

Comment: In my MVC application I had a connection string name like this: <add name="DALDevices3.DeviceContextConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.... so I removed the connection string since it is code first and still received the same error.  I put the connection string back like this: name="DALDevices3.DeviceContext" connectionString="Data Source=....  and the application works.  So a connection string is not required in the DAL application, but is needed in the consuming application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my MVC application I had a connection string name like this:

```
<add name="DALDevices3.DeviceContextConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=....
```

so I removed the connection string since it is code first and still received the same error. I put the connection string back like this:

```
<add name="DALDevices3.DeviceContext" connectionString="Data Source=....
```

and the application works. So a connection string is not required in the DAL application, but is needed in the consuming application.